# System ("pause") in unittest

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I've got Python application which is compiled to .exe.
In some cases, program terminates with sys.exit (), but to not close console window I'm doing it with code below, which works fine:

```
try:
    sys.exit()
except SystemExit:
    raise
finally:
    os.system("pause")
```

The problem is, that I need to test if my code raises SystemExit, but due to filnally block, tests cannot pass - they are just infinite.
Is there any possibility, to let unittest pass `os.system("pause")`?
I can add a default parameter, which will prevent pausing, but it will be complicated in my case - if there is any possibility I would like to do it in unittests.

Comment: Why are you performing a unit test on an application level?

Comment: simply patch `os.system` for that test

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abrams - I'm running `main()` function with specific parameters and check if it raises SystemExit - how to test this not in unittests (I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly)?

@kwarunek - can you say something more?

Answer (score 3):

I would simply mock `os.system`. More over even `sys.exit` to assert if it is called.

```
# your_module.py
import sys 
import os


def something():
    try:
        sys.exit()
    except SystemExit:
        raise
    finally:
        os.system("pause")
```

And the test

```
import unittest
import your_module
try:
    from unittest.mock import patch
except ImportError:
    from mock import patch


class TestSysexit(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('your_module.os.system')
    def test_system_exit(self, mock_os_system):

        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
            your_module.something()
        mock_os_system.assert_called_once_with('pause')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

mock and patch is in `unittest.mock` on python3 and in mock library on python2.

Comment: As I see, mock is new in Python 3.3 - I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: on python2 `pip install mock` `from mock import patch`